# Is it possible to publish tags with Jenkins Git Publisher via an environment variable?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using Jenkins to build some code and, as part of the build job's "Execute Shell", I create a tag via an environment variable `$BUILD_VERSION`.

I then try to use the Git Publisher plugin. I populate the "Tag to push" field with `$BUILD_VERSION` (I've also tried `${BUILD_VERSION}` and had no success there).

I create it thus:

```
export BUILD_VERSION=`node -e "console.log(require('./package.json').version);"`
```

When I run the build, the logs show this:

```
 > git tag -l $BUILD_VERSION # timeout=10
ERROR: Publisher hudson.plugins.git.GitPublisher aborted due to exception
hudson.AbortException: Tag $BUILD_VERSION does not exist and Create Tag is not specified, so failing.
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitPublisher.perform(GitPublisher.java:287)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:770)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:734)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:683)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1784)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
```

So, it appears that the environment variable isn't being resolved by the publisher.

The GIT client plugin is at version 1.18.0.
The GIT plugin is at vesion 2.3.

Am I doing something wrong or is this just not supported?

Comment: Doesn't work for me even for tags `*` and `'*'` for some strange reason. These work from the shell:  `git tag -l '*'`

Comment: This problem looks similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43058461/741249)